# Restore file : error: path 'app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb' is unmerged

Tags: git, github

Revert file to original before the change.

```
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
    both modified:   app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
    both modified:   app/form_models/message/new_conversation_form.rb
```

When I do

```
 git restore app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
error: path 'app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb' is unmerged
```

What is wrong? I basically need to disregard the change for these files, but no other files that I changed.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

#### First:

```
git reset app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
```

#### Second:

```
git restore app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb
```